# ActivityMapper, dealing with regions which don't change a lot

Tags: gwt, activity-manager, gwt-activities

I'm new with GWT and recently I've added Actvivities, Places and ActivityMappers to my code. I have one ActivityManager-ActivityMapper per each region. Regions like the header or the menu dont't change a lot so I have to write a lot of boilerplate code in the ActivityMapper for load the same Presenter every time but with a different constructor. For every possible Place I have to write another constructor for the Presenter in order to take the instance given by the ActivityMapper. There's any way to do that easier? Moreover, I'm not happy with the idea of creating a new Presenter every time that we move to a new place(even if you are going to load the same Presenter). In fact I have a big problem with that, cause my activities never die and they keep receiving events.

Comment: I've solved (provisionally) the problem about having multiple instances of the same Presenter. I stil have them, they don't finish. But at least they don't receive more events from views. I've used the class    HandlerRegistration for every handle that I had binded to my view. Like this:    handlerRegistration = new HandlerRegistrarion();an then in the mayStop() method of the Activity I've put this:    handlerRegistration.removeHandler();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When an `ActivityMapper` returns the exact same `Activity` instance (reference equality, i.e. `==`, not `equals()`) as previously, then the activity is not restarted, and the *region* is not touched. This is a deliberate optimization for those cases of regions that don't change often (e.g. headers or menus, or a *master* region in a master-detail setup). This is also the reason for the `CachingActivityMapper` (and `FilteredActivityMapper`, specifically designed to be used with the `CachingActivityMapper` in a master-detail setup)

In your case, it seems like you're imposing a rule to yourself that makes it *hard* for you to take advantage of this optimization: you're passing the current place to your activity's constructor, for no apparent reason.

Comment: You couldn't be more right. Passing the current place to my activity is meaningless. About the optimization, I hadn't heard before. I've changed the code and now is running perfectly fine.